# How to use positive regex lookahead to match, but exclude the lookahead part?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The lines to match against are

```
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d__part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2short_part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2short__part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2_part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2__part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2full_part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2full__part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2short-part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2-part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2full-part3.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part4.extension
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d__part4.extension
```

The desired match should give exactly `part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d` for all the above lines except the last two lines. That is to say, the "stem" has an arbitrary number of `part1`, an `optional part2 (in limited forms)`, and must ends with `part3.extension`.

Right now, I only got as far as

```
(?P<stem>[[:alnum:]_-]+)(?=(|part2short|part2|part2full))[_-]+part3\.extension
```

,by which the matched "stem" values for the lines above are

```
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2short
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2short_
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2_
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2full
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2full_
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2short
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2
part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d_part2full
```

Could you help to comment how to match exactly `part1a_part1b__part1c_part1d` from all the above lines except the last two lines, if it is possible ?

Comment: What's the expected output **exactly**? Like when are we supposed to match `part1` and when are we supposed to match `part1_`?

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks for your efforts ! `part1` would be perfect.

Comment: What about `^[^_]+`?

Comment: @ctwheels Oh... My examples were misleading...  I have to modify it a bit.

Comment: @ctwheels Could you help to check the current form of the question ? Many thanks !

Comment: What distinguishes the part that you want extracted?

Comment: @ctwheels The `"stem"` has a `optional part2 (in limited forms)`, and must ends with `part3.extension`. Is this possible ?

Comment: Maybe [`^(?P<stem>[^_]+_[^_]+__[^_]+_[^_]+)(?=.*part3\.extension$)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZcVxbA/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex using a non-greedy match, a lookahead with an optional match:

```
(?m)^(?P<stem>[[:alnum:]_-]+?)(?=(?:[_-]+part2(?:short|full)?)?[_-]+part3\.extension$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Zmftn/3)

`(?=(?:[_-]+part2(?:short|full)?)?[_-]+part3\.extension$)` is a positive lookahead that asserts line ends with `[-_]part3.extension` with optional `[-_]part2...` string before.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts ! However, `part2` is highlighted in the online demo, which is not desired. Could you help to comment how to improve ?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I somehow missed one `?` in the regex while posting the answer earlier.

Comment: Wow it works ! Thank you very much for your help ! I will try to understand your formula :D

Answer (score 1):

You could match the first 4 parts with the text and the underscores and use a positive lookahead that asserts that the string ends with part3.extension:

[`^(?P<stem>[^_]+_[^_]+__[^_]+_[^_]+)(?=.*part3\.extension$)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZcVxbA/2)

**That would match:**

```
^                     # Begin of the string
(?P<stem>             # Named captured group stem
[^_]+_                # Match not _ one or more times, then _
[^_]+__               # Match not _ one or more times, then __
[^_]+_                # Match not _ one or more times, then _
[^_]+                 # # Match not _ one or more times
)                     # Close named capturing group
(?=                   # A positive lookahead that asserts what follows
  .*part3\.extension$ # Match part3.extension at the end of the string
)                     # Close lookahead
```